# Adding List<CustomerInfo> to List view in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an application where I am getting the data inside `List<CustomerInfo>` I want to display this data in List View. How can i do it. Currently I am able to display the data in the LogCat. But I have No clue how can I go forward with displaying data in listview.

```
List<CustomerInfo> customerInfo;
        // Database Handler declarations
        db = new DatabaseHandler(this, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        checkDbExists = checkDataBase();
        if(checkDbExists){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Table exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            customerInfo = db.getInfoForSelectedCategory(strCategoryName);


            for (CustomerInfo ccinf : customerInfo) {
                String log = "Id: " + ccinf.getID() + " ,Name: "
                        + ccinf.getName() + " ,Category: "
                        + ccinf.getCategory() + " ,Email: " + ccinf.getEmail()
                        + " ,Contact: " + ccinf.getContact() + " ,Address: "
                        + ccinf.getAddress();
                Log.d("Record:  ", log);
            }
```

Comment: ListViews get set adapters. There are basic ones or you can implement complex ones. Google for listview adapter examples there are tons

Comment: Add your Adapter and listview code .Without adapter binding data not showing in listview

Comment: Got the thing Running thank you guys..

Answer (score 2):

since your listv view consist of custom object therefore you need a custom adapter to do this . [read here](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92) how to create a custom adpater.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this tutorial [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)..
only you need to extend your adapter class ArrayAdapter< CustomerInfo > in place of ArrayAdapter< String >. I hope this will help you :)